# Web3j - How to get timestamp for contract creation time?

Tags: android, ethereum, web3-java

I've successfully deployed a contract using

`Optional<TransactionReceipt> receipt = Contract.deploy(...).send().getTransactionReceipt();`

The receipt how ever doesn't return a timestamp.
It returns the transaction hash and the blocknumber.

How would I use the web3j library to get the timestamp of the contract creation time?

Answer (score 0):

You get the timestamp from the block (where the contract creation transaction was included).

```
let block = await web3.eth.getBlock(nr);
let date = new Date(Number(block.timestamp) * 1000)
```

Comment: I need the syntax for the Java library implementation Web3j. It doesn't have a ```.getBlock``` method

Answer (score 0):

If you have a transaction receipt, you can get a Date object as follows.

```
TransactionReceipt txnReceipt = ...
...
EthBlock txnBlock = web3j.ethGetBlockByHash(txnReceipt.getBlockHash(),true).send();
long txnBlockTimestamp = txnBlock.getBlock().getTimestamp().longValueExact() * 1000;
Date blockDate = new Date(txnBlockTimestamp);
```